# Вернуть стандартный цвет блока при нажатии на другой

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток!

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с jQuery.

Есть 10 div'ов с одним классом, по умолчанию они чёрные. При нажатии на любой из них один div подсвечивается, но если нажать на соседний, то он тоже подсвечивается, а старый не вернется в цвет, который был по умолчанию.

Заранее спасибо.  :)

Comment: По клику сначала покрасьте все в чёрный, а потом уже подсветите нужный

Comment: @sdfsdfxcv, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: для тех кто не знает, это классическая задача для css https://jsfiddle.net/oceog/h5kzLjvz/

Comment: @eicto, блин, я надеялся там какия-нибудь магия с :focus (и для выполнения условия там чекбоксы скорее нужны)

Comment: кстати, вопрос интересный, почему вот это не работает... https://jsfiddle.net/oceog/h1tcthw0/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.foo').on('click', function() {
    $('.foo').each(function() {
        $(this).css({'background-color': '#000'});
    });
    $(this).css({'background-color': '#999'});
});
```

Не помню только, может, надо писать в camel-case для css: backgroundColor.

Comment: А зачем писать `each()`, если можно сделать так: `$('.foo').css({"background-color": "#000"});`?

Comment: `$('.foo')` — это обращение к первому элементу с классом "foo". Не все браузеры применяют это ко всем элементам с таким классом. Могу ошибаться, конечно, но у меня не всегда срабатывало, пришлось each() использовать.

И еще: в моем ответе отсутсвуют кавычки — спешка :)

Comment: @densmith, вы не правы и никакого `$.each` тут не нужно. `$('.foo')` это массив элементов с классом `foo` и все действия применяются относительно этого массива и касаются всех его элементов. Правильнее было бы сделать так: `var $foo = $('.foo'); $foo.click(function() ...`

Comment: @Олег Б, вот описание $().each(): http://jquery-docs.ru/Core/each/#demo

Там самый первый пример в статье до жути похож на обсуждаемый тут. И если говорите, что кто-то неправ, будьте добры, подкрепляйте свои аргументы. Тогда я соглашусь.

Comment: @densmith https://jsfiddle.net/oceog/th8vqsar/ :)